# Smooth transition of block elements when removing, with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create a smooth transition when user removes a block from the stack, but using pure JS. This example describe what i'm trying to do. It's easy to make transitions with "display: none", but the problem is make the block above fall smoothly.

```js
function removesBlock(e){
  e.style.opacity = 0;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    e.style.display = "none"
  },255)
}
```

```css
.block{
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
background: black;
margin-bottom: 20px;
transition: .25s opacity;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer:

Adjust the `height` property as well

Adjust CSS:

```css
    transition: .25s opacity, .25s height;
```

Adjust JS:

```js
    e.style.height = 0;
```

### Example:

```js
function removesBlock(e){
  e.style.opacity = 0;
  e.style.height = 0;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    e.style.display = "none"
  },255)
}
```

```css
.block{
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
background: black;
margin-bottom: 20px;
transition: .25s opacity, .25s height;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain how  `removeBlock(this)` works ? Isn't `this`  a reference to the `Window`object ?

Comment: @Noob When an Attribute Event passes `this` it is referring to the `element` that the event is **attached to**. It's worth noting that in my personal opinion I think that attribute events should be completely removed from use, and I would encourage any developer to attach events using `addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the height to zero transition animation, I am not sure if this is exactly you want though.

```js
function removesBlock(e){
  e.style.opacity = 0;
  e.style.height = 0;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    e.style.display = "none"
  },255)
}
```

```css
.block{
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
background: black;
margin-bottom: 20px;
transition: opacity .25s;
transition: height .25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
<div class="block" onclick="removesBlock(this)">
</div>
```